# Trying to generate a simple pop-up

Tags: android, android-xml

I am trying to generate a simple popup on click of a button, but due to some reason it is not working. Below is my code:

```
     public class Product extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    setContentView(R.layout.product);
    String fontPath = "fonts/georgia.ttf";
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

    final Animation animScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_scale);


    Button Particle =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
    Button MDF=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button Laminates=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button Ply =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4); 
    Button Floor=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button Door=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    Button EdgeBand=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
    Button ModFur=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);



    Particle.setTypeface(tf);
    MDF.setTypeface(tf);
    Laminates.setTypeface(tf);
    Ply.setTypeface(tf);
    Floor.setTypeface(tf);
    Door.setTypeface(tf);
    EdgeBand.setTypeface(tf);
    ModFur.setTypeface(tf);

   /* Particle.startAnimation(animScale);
    MDF.startAnimation(animScale);
    Laminates.startAnimation(animScale);
    Ply.startAnimation(animScale);
    Floor.startAnimation(animScale);
    Door.startAnimation(animScale);
    EdgeBand.startAnimation(animScale);
    ModFur.startAnimation(animScale); */


    Particle.setOnClickListener(Par);

}


private View.OnClickListener Par = new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){

        openNewDialog();


    }
};



private void openNewDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setItems(R.array.pop,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface,int i){
        if(i==0){
            Intent about = new Intent(Product.this,AboutUs.class);
            startActivity(about);
        }
        if(i==1){
            Intent about = new Intent(Product.this,AboutUs.class);
            startActivity(about);
        }

    }}); 

}
```

In the Strings.xml file:

```
     <array name="pop">
      <item name="easy_label">Key Features</item>
      <item name="medium_label">Advantages</item> 
     </array>
```

The layout file for the said activity in xml:

```
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/universalbg"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
       android:text="@string/btn2"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
       android:textSize="24dp"
       android:textStyle="bold"  />
        </RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView 
     android:layout_marginTop="10dip" 
     android:layout_marginBottom="03dip" 
     android:id="@+id/Scroll" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/insidebut"
    android:text="@string/BTn2"
    android:textColor="#900606" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/insidebut"
    android:text="@string/BTn3"
    android:textColor="#900606" />


 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/insidebut"
    android:text="@string/BTn4"
    android:textColor="#900606" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/insidebut"
    android:text="@string/BTn5"
    android:textColor="#900606" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/insidebut"
    android:text="@string/BTn6"
    android:textColor="#900606" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/insidebut"
    android:text="@string/BTn7"
    android:textColor="#900606" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/insidebut"
    android:text="@string/BTn8"
    android:textColor="#900606" />
```

```
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how one can forget it, but could you actually describe what happens? I'm sure that you could do better then "it is not working". What do you do, what do you expect, why do you expect this, what actually happens, are there any errors, did you do any debugging/tracing yourself, what is the state of all your variables, are all functions triggered. Honestly, how do you expect one to have interest in this question if you yourself don't seem to have?

Comment: That is what is astonishing me, I have no log cat errors! I have normal program execution and when I click the button nothing happens, the sole reason to ask about this question here was to gather expert advise where I fail.

Comment: Yes if I add some other functionality to the said onClickListener, it works, like trying to open a new intent.

Comment: Then actually add that! " I press the button, but then nothing happens. I have checked the log... etc". We cannot guess these things! Then, add some logging to your onclick function, to show that it actually is triggered. And explain what you expect to happen in your code, and check if/why it happens. etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `show()` in order to actually display the dialog.

```
private void openNewDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setItems(R.array.pop,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface,int i){
        if(i==0){
            Intent about = new Intent(Product.this,AboutUs.class);
            startActivity(about);
        }
        if(i==1){
            Intent about = new Intent(Product.this,AboutUs.class);
            startActivity(about);
        }

    }}).show(); // Here

}
```